# Firing multiple jQuery event listeners consecutively

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

Say I'm doing something like this:

```
$('#demo').click(func1);
$('#demo').click(func2);
```

In Firefox that makes `func1()` run after `func2()` but not on IE.

Any ideas?

Comment: It worked in Firefox for me: http://jsfiddle.net/Y2aKU/ - that is, jQuery fires the handlers in the order they were bound.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Binding same event to same element multiple times is not necessary, though it has no problem with jQuery.

Just simply write

```
$('#demo').click(function() {
  // serial execution of functions
  func1();
  func2();
});
```

If you need to bind click for multiple elements then procedure will be

```
$('#demo1, #demo2').click(function() {
   // do your stuff
});
```

you can use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on) for event bind like:

```
$('#demo').on('click', function() {
  func1();
  func2();
});
```

Comment: jQuery has no problem binding more than one handler for the same event on the same element, and it is supposed to ensure that (from the doco) "Event handlers bound to an element are called in the same order that they were bound". In fact, (also from the doco) "As of jQuery 1.4, the same event handler can be bound to an element multiple times."

Comment: @nnnnnn I got your point, but isn't it better to avoid this thing, shouldn't we go for good

Answer (score 2):

Instead of binding event twice call both function in click event. You can do it without binding event twice like this.

```
$('#demo').click(function (){

func1(); 

func2();

});
```

If you want to bind it multiple times then you can do like this, Binding event for multiple times without good reason should be avoided though. [Demo on JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gZrjd/2/)

```
$('#demo').bind('click', function(){
   alert("fun1");})
    .bind('click', function(){
  alert("fun2");
 });
```

Comment: _"Binding event for multiple times without good reason could cause problem and is highly discouraged."_ - Can you back that assertion up with some doco references? jQuery is designed to allow multiple bindings, as is the (plain JS) `addEventListener()` (and IE's `attachEvent()`). Why would it cause problems? Who discourages it?

Comment: I said without good reason ... it is highly discouraged. As in OP I feel there was not a good reason for binding event for multiple times

Comment: I code as per your answer 95% of the time. But, doing it as shown in the question should not cause any problems. jQuery supports it, and supports it _better_ than the native `.addEventListener()`, because jQuery is supposed to guarantee the order, while `.addEventListener()` on its own doesn't (which is why the behaviour described in the question is weird).

Comment: Keeping your concerns in view I have changed my answer, I would like to know what you say about it now?